# Do I need permission to programatically post on my wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to programatically post a new story on a page I own. Do I need to ask Facebook for permissions to do that? When I invoke `Facebook -> post` I get an error: `(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`.

I wanted to request the `publish_actions` permission, but it seems to be permission for my app to post to app users' walls, which is not what I intend to do, I just want to publish on my own wall.

This is my code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'my app id',
  'app_secret' => 'my app secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
  'default_access_token' => 'the access token'
  ]);


$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://example.com/link/for/today',
  'message' => 'This is the link for today',
  ];

try {
  $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No, to post to a page _as_ the page, you will need permissions `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`, and you will need to get a page access token first.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to convert this to an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post to a page *as* the page, you will need permissions `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`, and you will need to get a page access token first ... and then use that to create the post.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

Comment: Yes, and make sure you request those permissions following these instructions: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php